# Find location of currently sourced .bash_profile

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to modify a .bash_profile on a system where it already exists, but it's not in the usual location where I'd expect to find it ($HOME/.bash_profile).  Is there a way to show the location of the file that's being sourced on login?

Comment: does the `.bash_profile` reference the file it's being sourced from? You could read through the file, when line matches variable, cut the string with a delimiter? Anyway can you show some code that you worked on already?

Comment: Start a login shell with `bash -l -x`, and the debug output will indicate every file that is sourced.

Comment: @itChi I can't find the .bash_profile file.  I only know it exists because custom paths and behavior are set in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

If `~/.bash_profile` does not exist, `~/.profile` is sourced instead.

Comment: `.bash_login` first if it exists, then `.profile` if there is no `.bash_login`.

Comment: There is no `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`.

Comment: `/etc/profile` and other possibly other `profile*` files under `/etc`? Good luck.